# UIActivity indicator is not working on iPhone 4 (Retina)

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, uiactivityindicatorview, retina-display

I have an `UIActivityIndicator` which is working as well as good in iPhone 3G simulator/device, but it is not working on Simulator/Device for iPhone 4(Retina). I would like to mention that it is on a black background.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'not working'. Is it showing up incorrectly, not being displayed on the screen etc. Screenshots would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem sometime back. It was solved by changing the indicator style to `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge` and giving a contrasting color(I chose black) to the background. The problem actually is that it's not visible.

Comment: Actually the style is set to be UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge and the Background is also black.

Comment: Actually I did not notice that it really was in grey style, changing it to white, helped me, thanks.

Comment: Changing indicator to gray helped me too, but I don't quite understand. Indicator should be quite vissible even on white background (it certaily is on older iphones) why is it then that it is hidden on retina display? I tried to set background color to something else other than white, but big white still wasn't visible

Answer (score 2):

The UIActivityIndicator will not show up immediately.

If you have code such as this:

```
//(pseudo-code)
//Create UIActivityIndicator
//show UIActivityIndicator
//do some other stuff expecting view to show
```

the UIActivityIndicator will not show up, as the UIActivityIndicator will only show on the next run loop of the program.

You can get around this by

```
{
    //create UIActivityIndicator
    //show UIActivityIndicator
    [self performSelector:@selector(doOtherStuff) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

-(void)doOtherStuff {
    //do stuff 
}
```

The performSelector means that the doOtherStuff is performed on the next run loop, when the UIActivityIndicator will show.

You also have to add it as a subview to the view in which you want it to show.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you’re displaying the spinner from a thread that’s not the main thread? You can try this assert to find out whether you’re on the main thread:

```
NSAssert([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread],
    @"This should be run from the main thread.");
```

If the assert fails, you can dispatch the call to the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // display the spinner
});
```

Anyway, without seeing the code we are all just guessing.

Comment: I am creating a splash screen, and it does not run in backthread. Anyway it does work in iPhone 3G and iPad.